# Implementing the headers as FloatingGroupExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom listview in `ListFragment` with  3 types of headers(1st.Green Background, 2nd.Black Background, 3rd.Gray background), as you can see in the [video](http://youtu.be/jJb85Om52XA).

I want to customize the green header, i.e on click of the green header all the views(items) between the next green header must be minimized, & also again clicking in that green header the views which were minimized should be exapanded.

The same functionality like [FloatingGroupExpandableListView](https://github.com/diegocarloslima/FloatingGroupExpandableListView) which uses some dummy items, In my case the views have to be customized.

I have no Idea to how can I modify my code to accomplish this task.

```
public class ContentsFragment extends ListFragment  implements OnTouchListener
{
final Context context = getActivity();
    private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;
    Activity temp = getActivity();
    TextView tv1,tv3;
    String []s = new String[500];
    ArrayList<GS> q = new ArrayList<GS>();
    ListView lv;
    int count=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     DBAdapter db = DBAdapter.getDBAdapter(getActivity());

     if (!db.checkDatabase())   
      db.createDatabase(getActivity());

     db.openDatabase();

     q = db.getData();

     mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity());

     mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART I", null, null, null, null));//group
     mAdapter.addSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(0).getA_name(),null,null,null,null));//child
     mAdapter.addItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(0).getAS_name(), q.get(0).getDesc_art(),q.get(0).getExtra(),q.get(0).getPart(),q.get(0).getItalic()));//child


     for (int i = 1; i <= 14; i++) {
  if(i==5) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART II", null, null, null, null));
  if(i==12) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART III", null, null, null, null));

      if (!(q.get(i).getA_name().trim().equals(q.get(i-1).getA_name().trim()))) {

      mAdapter.addSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getA_name(), null,null,null,null));
     }
     if(!(q.get(i).getExtra()==null))
  mAdapter.addGraySeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getExtra(),null,null,null,null));//child

     mAdapter.addItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getAS_name(), q.get(i).getDesc_art(),q.get(i).getExtra(),q.get(i).getPart(),q.get(i).getItalic()));
   }
   for (int i = 15; i < 36; i++) {
  if (!(q.get(i).getA_name().trim().equals(q.get(i-1).getA_name().trim()))) {

      mAdapter.addSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getA_name(), null,null,null,null));

  }
  if(!(q.get(i).getExtra()==null))
      mAdapter.addGraySeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getExtra(),null,null,null,null));


  mAdapter.addItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getAS_name(), q.get(i).getDesc_art(),q.get(i).getExtra(),q.get(i).getPart(),q.get(i).getItalic()));

    }

      mAdapter.addItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(460).getAS_name(), q.get(460).getDesc_art(),q.get(460).getExtra(),q.get(460).getPart(),q.get(460).getItalic()));


   for (int i=36; i < 158; i++) {
    if(i==41) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART IV", null, null, null, null));//group
if(i==60) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART IVA", null, null, null, null));//group
if(i==61) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART V", null, null, null, null));


  if (!(q.get(i).getA_name().trim().equals(q.get(i-1).getA_name().trim()))) {

      mAdapter.addSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getA_name(), null,null,null,null));

  }
   if(!(q.get(i).getExtra()==null))
      mAdapter.addGraySeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getExtra(),null,null,null,null));


  mAdapter.addItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getAS_name(), q.get(i).getDesc_art(),q.get(i).getExtra(),q.get(i).getPart(),q.get(i).getItalic()));

    }
          mAdapter.addItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(461).getAS_name(), q.get(461).getDesc_art(),q.get(461).getExtra(),q.get(461).getPart(),q.get(461).getItalic()));

     for (int i=158; i < 210; i++) {
  if(i==163) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART VI", null, null, null, null));

  if (!(q.get(i).getA_name().trim().equals(q.get(i-1).getA_name().trim()))) {

      mAdapter.addSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getA_name(), null,null,null,null));

  }
   if(!(q.get(i).getExtra()==null))
      mAdapter.addGraySeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getExtra(),null,null,null,null));


  mAdapter.addItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getAS_name(), q.get(i).getDesc_art(),q.get(i).getExtra(),q.get(i).getPart(),q.get(i).getItalic()));

    }
      mAdapter.addItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(462).getAS_name(), q.get(462).getDesc_art(),q.get(462).getExtra(),q.get(462).getPart(),q.get(462).getItalic()));

     for (int i=210; i < 218; i++) {
  if (!(q.get(i).getA_name().trim().equals(q.get(i-1).getA_name().trim()))) {

      mAdapter.addSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getA_name(), null,null,null,null));

  }
   if(!(q.get(i).getExtra()==null))
      mAdapter.addGraySeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getExtra(),null,null,null,null));

  mAdapter.addItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getAS_name(), q.get(i).getDesc_art(),q.get(i).getExtra(),q.get(i).getPart(),q.get(i).getItalic()));

    }
      mAdapter.addItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(463).getAS_name(), q.get(463).getDesc_art(),q.get(463).getExtra(),q.get(463).getPart(),q.get(463).getItalic()));
      for (int i=218; i < 244; i++) {

  if (!(q.get(i).getA_name().trim().equals(q.get(i-1).getA_name().trim()))) {

      mAdapter.addSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getA_name(), null,null,null,null));

  }
   if(!(q.get(i).getExtra()==null))
      mAdapter.addGraySeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getExtra(),null,null,null,null));

  mAdapter.addItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getAS_name(), q.get(i).getDesc_art(),q.get(i).getExtra(),q.get(i).getPart(),q.get(i).getItalic()));

    }
      mAdapter.addItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(464).getAS_name(), q.get(464).getDesc_art(),q.get(464).getExtra(),q.get(464).getPart(),q.get(464).getItalic()));

      for (int i=244; i < 459; i++) {
if(i==248) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART VII", null, null, null, null));
if(i==249) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART VIII", null, null, null, null));
if(i==257) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART IX", null, null, null, null));
if(i==273) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART IXA", null, null, null, null));
if(i==291) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART X", null, null, null, null));
if(i==293) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART XI", null, null, null, null));
if(i==314) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART XII", null, null, null, null));
if(i==353) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART XIII", null, null, null, null));
if(i==360) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART XIV", null, null, null, null));
if(i==377) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART XIVA", null, null, null, null));
if(i==379) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART XV", null, null, null, null));
if(i==386) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART XVI", null, null, null, null));
if(i==400) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART XVII", null, null, null, null));
if(i==421) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART XIX", null, null, null, null));
if(i==431) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART XX", null, null, null, null));
if(i==432) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART XXI", null, null, null, null));
if(i==455) mAdapter.addGreenSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper("PART XXII", null, null, null, null));

  if (!(q.get(i).getA_name().trim().equals(q.get(i-1).getA_name().trim()))) {

      mAdapter.addSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getA_name(), null,null,null,null));

  }
   if(!(q.get(i).getExtra()==null))
      mAdapter.addGraySeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getExtra(),null,null,null,null));

  mAdapter.addItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getAS_name(), q.get(i).getDesc_art(),q.get(i).getExtra(),q.get(i).getPart(),q.get(i).getItalic()));

    }

setListAdapter(mAdapter);



 }

 //Adapter Class
 private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

 private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
 private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
 private static final int TYPE_GRAY_SEPARATOR = 2;
 private static final int TYPE_GREEN_SEPARATOR = 3;
 private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_GREEN_SEPARATOR + 1;
 private TreeSet<Integer> mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();

 private TreeSet<Integer> mGraySeparatorsSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();

 private TreeSet<Integer> mGreenSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();


 private ArrayList<ContentWrapper> mData = new ArrayList<ContentWrapper>();
 private LayoutInflater mInflater;


 public MyCustomAdapter(Context context)
 {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); 
 }

 public void addItem(ContentWrapper value) {
    mData.add(value);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
 }

 public void addSeparatorItem(ContentWrapper value) {
    mData.add(value);
    // save separator position
    mSeparatorsSet.add(mData.size() - 1);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
 }

 public void addGraySeparatorItem(ContentWrapper value) {
    mData.add(value);
    // save separator position
    mGraySeparatorsSet.add(mData.size() - 1);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
 }   

 public void addGreenSeparatorItem(ContentWrapper value) {
    mData.add(value);
    // save separator position
    mGreenSeparatorsSet.add(mData.size() - 1);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
 }   


 public ContentWrapper getItem(int position) {
    return mData.get(position);
 }

 @Override
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int viewType = TYPE_ITEM;
    if(mSeparatorsSet.contains(position))
       viewType = TYPE_SEPARATOR;
    else if(mGraySeparatorsSet.contains(position)) 
        viewType = TYPE_GRAY_SEPARATOR; 
    else if(mGreenSeparatorsSet.contains(position)) 
        viewType = TYPE_GREEN_SEPARATOR; 


    return viewType;
    // return mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
 }

 @Override
 public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
 }

 public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
 }

 public long getItemId(int position) {
    Log.v("getItemId Position", ""+position);
    return position;

 }

 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        switch (type) {
        case TYPE_ITEM:
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.white, null);
            holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            break;
        case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.black, null);
            holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
            break;
        case 2:
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gray, null);
            holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewGray);
            break;
        case 3:
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.green, null);
            holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparatorGreen);
            break;

        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    } holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position).getItem());

    getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    if (type == TYPE_ITEM) {
        holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) 

            {
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.description);

              TextView desc = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                TextView part = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                TextView italic = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

                      italic.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
                title.setText(mData.get(position).getItem());
                desc.setText(mData.get(position).getItemDescription());
                part.setText(mData.get(position).getPart());
                italic.setText(mData.get(position).getItalic());

          dialog.show();
         dialog.setCancelable(true);
     dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

            }
       });

    }else if(type == 1) {
        holder.textView.setOnClickListener(null);
    }
    else  if(type == 2)
    {
        holder.textView.setOnClickListener(null);
    }

return convertView;
}
}
public static class ViewHolder {
public TextView textView;
public TextView header;
 int previousTop = 0;
}


public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return false;
}
}
```

Thank you, please help . . . . .

Comment: Sorry , _The question is not widely applicable to a large audience._ But, I am looking forward for the answer from the official source, or from the other who have done this work before !

Comment: What you're trying to do is the exact behavior of the `ExpandableListView`. In the video you posted(awful example of what you want btw) I see two types of headers + the normal row(I don't know if this is what you mean by 3 types of headers). What you would want to do is use an `ExpandableListView` where the group view is the green part, the rest(black title and normal row) will be two types of child rows.

Comment: @Luksprog If you watch the video carefully, it is also showing the header with gray background, The video is displaying the output of the above code ! There are 3 type of headers 1st.Green Background, 2nd.Black Background, 3rd.Gray background !!!  Then the normal row of white background are clickable items, which when clicked show data in a dialog !!! So, Green part will be the group view  & the rest(Black title, Gray title, normal row) will be 3 types of child rows.

Comment: I've seen it now, you're scrolling to fast in that video. *So, Green part will be the group view & the rest(Black title, Gray title, normal row) will be 3 types of child rows.* - that's the idea I was pointing in the first comment, right now it seems you're using a simple `ListView`.

Comment: @Luksprog Yes Right now it is a simple listview with 3 types of headers

Comment: The question I asked is very important for my project, the  answer of my [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939819/implementing-floatinggroupexpandablelistview-in-a-listview-consisting-2-types-of) does not provide enough details, & I am looking for a detailed answer

Answer (score -1):

I did not reviewed your code, but here is an idea how to achieve it:

Obviously you cannot really minimize it all, as the list view only present part of the views while the actual amount of views to minimize may be much larger.

Also after you minimized all the views that need to be minimized, you cannot present them as empty views(height = 0), because than your list will be empty.

So to solve the second problem, I recommend to manipulate the data to exclude those views.

The first problem is much harder to solve, and you probably will need to compromise some how.
You can minimize all the visible views, but than your entire list view might get smaller or a hall will be created inside it. And after the minimization is complete you will update the data, and get all the reset of the views that supposed to be visible there in a boom.
This will probably work well if you will have 1 or two views to minimize, how ever generally this is not a perfect idea.

The other solution is to forget about list view, and actually have all the views in memory, I think this the only way of achieving it.

In general this is very difficult task.

Comment: I didn't get you what are u saying, Now 1 solution that could work is displaying all the data from mChilds, & in `getChildView` method, I can check the type of text, & according to which I can inflate headers(black,or gray). Thanks though